Wkhtmltopdf library showing footer in pdf generated in windows but not showing with same code on ubuntu 22.04
I am providing options as follows:
options = {
    "page-size": "Letter",
    "orientation": "landscape",
    "margin-bottom": "50mm",
    "disable-smart-shrinking": None,
    "zoom": "0.5",
    "header-center": "YOUR HEADER",
    "encoding": "UTF-8",
     "footer-left": "This is a footer",
    "footer-font-size": 7,
    "footer-right": "[page]",
    "custom-header": [
       ("Accept-Encoding", "gzip"),
     ],
    "no-outline": None,
    "enable-local-file-access": None,
}

template = get_template("abc.html")

html = template.render(
    {
#some data provided in key value pair
    },
)

 pdf_data = pdfkit.from_string(html, options=options)

Now I have also generated pdf using following change in from_string method:
pdf_data = pdfkit.from_string(html, False, options=options)

In both cases, PDFs are generated as expected (with a footer) on Windows. However, in both cases on Ubuntu, no footer is being generated.
I tried passing the above options in code running on Ubuntu. I was expecting footers but didn't get them. But the same code generated footers in Windows.
For hints you can check this issue here
